# equation for an hexagon with rounded corners

Tags: geometry, implicit-function

I know a simple equation for a squircle, $x^4+y^4=a^4$

[image: a squircle]

What would be the equation for an hexagon with rounded corners?

In the equation, how can I take in account for the angle of rotation of the hexagon about its center?

Answer (score 3):

The following equation gives a rounded hexagon where $\theta$ can be changed in order to give any rotation of the hexagon about its centre and $r$ can be changed to affect the roundness of the hexagon itself. I found that $r=15$ works well. The value $10$ at the end of the equation can be increased to increase the size of the hexagon as well.
$$\sum_{n=1}^6 \Big|x\cos{\Big(\frac{\pi n}{3}+\theta\Big)}+y\sin{\Big(\frac{\pi n}{3}+\theta\Big)}-\frac{1}{6}\Big|^r=10$$

Comment: See this post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786335/is-there-a-function-that-draws-a-triangle-with-rounded-edges

Comment: Does $r$ need to be odd?

Comment: No, I just recommend that that value is used as it appears most visually appealing.

Answer (score 1):

polar 
$$ r = 5 + \frac{1}{5} \cos (6 \theta)   $$
looks very good. You can solve as rectangular using $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$

The 6 is fixed, but you may adjust the ratio of coefficients as you like, for visual effect.